# How to select and hide element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, element, hide

I have this code in my site that is auto generated and would like to get the `<p>` tag and hide it.

```
<div id="PD_superContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="//static.polldaddy.com/p/8895171.js"></script>
<noscript>&lt;a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/8895171"&gt;Take Our Poll&lt;/a&gt;</noscript>
<p></p>
```

Comment: great! that did the work.

Comment: One more thing, same code but would like to add some text to the <p> tag.  innerHTML?

Comment: `$('#PD_superContainer').nextUntil('p').last().next('p').html('your content')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
$('#PD_superContainer').nextUntil('p').last().next('p').hide()
```

using `nextAll('p')` might cause issues if there are any other `p` element